# SharePoint list not accepting copied excel data

Tags: 2010, list, excel, datasheet

Hello I am having an issue with a SharePoint list not accepting copied data from an excel sheet while in datasheet view.

The sheet has 130 rows of data

I have done this before and made sure the columns match and all the data in the list matches.

I get the following

> Error 3 cells could not be pasted. Some source rows which would have created new rows contained invalid values in required fields. These rows were skipped. Do you wish to continue with the operation and accept the changes. (Then it asks Yes No or Help.)

I click yes and from what it just said it should copy 127 of the rows but it only copies 14 of them instead.

I cannot find any similarity between the excluded rows and the accepted rows. Has anyone else had a similar issue before and if so what did you do?

EDIT:

I came to realize that the way two of the columns lined up it looked like both had data in the columns when really it was only in one of them. The second column was one of the required columns. I changed the column to be not required and it worked.

Thanks for everyone's input. I am marking tyshock's reply as the answer as his suggestion did help.

Comment: Which are the required columns? What does the Excel table have in these cells?

Comment: Hi @Aaron tyshock's answer is excellent, but I also have some extra information that you both may find useful in my answer to a related question. Namely, how to add multiple users to a User/Group column. :) 
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that dates and username fields are especially susceptible to these errors.  To paste a username in a field, that user has to 'exist' on that site.  Just being a valid domain user is not sufficient.  They must access the site at least once in order to get their userid associated with that site collection.  If you enter them via the standard forms, you avoid this restriction. I have also had difficulty adding users to a field that accepts multiple users.

What you need to do is paste small subsets of the rows until you identify an exact row which is causing the issue.  At that point, you can experiment and determine the exact field.   From there, it should be easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I did run into this issue but I decided to just clear that column of it's data and input it manually later.

Comment: @tyshock this is an excellent answer. If you would like to know how to add multiple users, I've figured this out, through many grueling hours of trial and error, and explained in detail on my [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163) linked above. :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy from excel to SharePoint list, in datasheet view is not very straight forward. I faced these problem twice ( not exactly similar like you, but very close). and both time I survived by

1. copying small number of elements. say 10-30  fields at a time
2. making sure fields are similar and same  number of fields have been chosen to paste.

Thanks